# How to create an object dynamically

Tags: android

I want to create an object on the fly, that is not assigned to a variable, and doesn't need a class definition.

In C#, it's possible via object initializers, or via `ExpandoObject` and `dynamic` keyword:

```
var ananymousObject = new { Property = "Value" }; // object initializer
```

or

```
dynamic instance = new ExpandoObject();
instance.Property = "Value";
```

How to do that in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HashMap`

```
HashMap<String, Object> anon = new HashMap<>();
anon.set("property", value);
```

Comment: How does a hashmap help? It can be reduced to just `Object value = new Object();`. Why the need for `HashMap`?

Comment: As I understand, OP wants to create an anonymous object where properties can be stored.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can write this "new ABC()" this creates anonymous object which doesn't have any reference here AB is any class name  like new String();

Answer (score 0):

Java is much more strict in this case. So the short answer is no, Java doesn't have an Expando. The syntax just doesn't support that.

However there is an Expando in Groovy which is a dynamic language on top of java.

BTW, If you're using Expando for tests, there are a lot of various Mock related solutions: EasyMock, Mockito, JMock to name a few.